# Tab icon guidelines and icons in general

Tags: android

i recently downloaded a free app and noticed that the icons on the apps tab were colored. and had a slight 3d perspective. so i just wanted to find out if there is anything wrong doing this in a commercial related application. because from reading the icons guideline documentation for android, they kind of sound very strict on things like that.

so are we allowed to create what is pleasing in the eyes and override the guidelines?.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector, you're misunderstanding the question. He's asking if it's okay not to follow the icon guidelines to the letter.

Sparrow, as long as you understand that on some phones (I think the Galaxy S is one example) the color schemes are different. Instead of gray tabs, they have blue (or some variation of color), so your app will look different on devices like that, and your colors may end up clashing with the theme on the phone. But you're free to do your design in any way you like; the design guidelines are there to try to keep apps looking consistent, but if you have a better idea for the design, I say absolutely go for it. :)

Comment: Hmm.. you have a point. i did not actually take that into too much consideration. it would be nice if there were different emulators from manufacturers, so one can test consistency.

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't worry about it too much, though. I imagine for the most part the theme won't make too much of a difference. I run Cyanogenmod on my Droid, and I had the notification bar set to black; only issue I had was the icons that were almost all black, but even then it wasn't a big deal, as you still had the white icons in the center.

Comment: well thanks for the info. you guys just saved me some headache in designing for the tabs. i can as well find free icons on the web for those tabs and focus on the more appealing ones i want to work on.  by the way, i just came up with a silly idea: created layers in photoshop with different range of colors and now testing icons with different blending modes on them. just to see if i can mimick the the phone themes. hope i get luck in that..  :)

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! You might even check on the xda-developers forums and see if you can get a copy of some of the 9-patch images from the different manufacturer ROMs; that would give you an even more accurate test.

Answer (score 0):

> so are we allowed to create what is
>   pleasing in the eyes and override the
>   guidelines?.. ;)

Yes, you can use whatever you like to your tabs. You can use entirely custom graphics and even dismiss the standard background (avoiding any clashes with standard settings differing on various phones as mentioned here) and/or icons completely. It's all up to you and your UI team.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the style, the latest [Android iconography guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html), actually recommend using a 'slight 3d perspective'.

> **Style**
>
> Use a distinct silhouette. Three-dimensional, front view, with a
>   slight perspective as if viewed from above, so that users perceive
>   some depth.

Answer (score -1):

No. Positively: No.

Especially if the icons' guidelines are strict. Especially if you want to use them in a "commercial related application". Just because they are in a free app, doesn't mean they're free. You can't even "just" take the idea and make the same icons by yourself (plagiarism).

I suggest you contact the owner of the rights, explain what it is you'd like to do and ask him/her for permission to use them for your project.

If you're not willing to pay for the use of icons, search for free icons on the web, there are tons.
e.g. http://www.freeiconsdownload.com

Comment: Are you sure you were answering this person's question?

Comment: sorry.. you misunderstood me there. i was refering to the icon design guidelines documentation for android. not the app. will edit my question to be more clear. sorry about that.. :)